# How to select specific cases within one variable to create a new variable?

Tags: r, list, split, startswith

I have a 'telephone' variable where one participant may have put their landline number, whilst others have put their mobile number. I want to pull out all the landline numbers from this variable and put them in their own column. So I end up with 2 columns, a mobile number column and a landline column in my data frame, rather than just the one telephone variable. I've tried to do this with the 'starts_with' function as all landline numbers start with '01'.

So my data looks something like this:

| participant | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 07710 123456 |
| 2 | 01254 456789 |
| 3 | 07720 666333 |

But I want to be able to select all the numbers that start with '01' and put them in their own column, so my output would look something like this:

| Participant | Number | Number2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 07710 123456 |  |
| 2 |  | 01254 456789 |
| 3 | 07720 666333 |  |

Is there a way of doing this please?
Or is there a way of deleting the numbers that start with '01'? I don't want to delete the row as participant 2 has valuable info in other variables in the data frame. Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are a few alternatives I can think of. Have a column for the phone number, and a column for the phone type. There should probably be one more column connecting it to a customer. Or if you dont care if they have a cell or landline, have a table for landlines and a table for cell phones.
Edit sorry I misread your question. Let melook again

Comment: What allows you to distinguish if it is a cell or landline? The only info you have provided is that you have a telephone 'variable' (so a list maybe?) and you want to split them into cell phone vs landline. Is there anything to help you distinguish them? If it is only a list with raw phone numbers then you wont be able to split them up. Please provide info on what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
numbr <- c('016097751673', '6097751673', '017736440981', '015059811232')
mobl <- NA
phone <- data.frame(numbr, mobl)
phone
         numbr mobl
1 016097751673 <NA>
2   6097751673 <NA>
3 017736440981 <NA>
4 015059811232 <NA>

phone$mobl <- grepl('^01', phone$numbr)
phone
         numbr  mobl
1 016097751673  TRUE
2   6097751673 FALSE
3 017736440981  TRUE
4 015059811232  TRUE
```

The `grepl` pattern `'^01', says look for '01' at the beginning of the string in phone$numbr, assign TRUE or FALSE if the patterns is found.

Comment: Btw ``as.data.frame(cbind(numbr, mobl))`` is dangerous, as ``cbind`` will coerce numeric values to characters if the other thing you are cbinding is a character. Just do ``data.frame(numbr, mobl)`` instead :)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to look at this. Your example works but I would like the code to put the 'FALSE' numbers into their own column, so using your example the '6097751673' number would have moved to the mobl column, and where it says 'TRUE', those columns would be blank. Do you know if there is a way of doing this please?